# Barcode EPL language

Tags: zebra-printers, epl

Good Morning!

Using EPL language for printing on Zebra RW 420 when printing a bar code using CODE 128 C, the beginning and end of the barcode are printed correctly, but the middle is printed a sort of "black box", as some bars were amended. What can it be?
I've tried to change the print density in the EPL source code, but not resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved!**

The error occurred because the number of spaces in bar code.

It was like this:

B135,596,0,1C,2,4,70,N,\"**4316 0307 3335 9700 0135 5511 8000 0095 4855 1020 2574**\"

The right was thus:

B135,596,0,1C,2,4,70,N,\"**43160307333597000135551180000095485510202574**\"